# Android Phonegap fatal error

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

I just started with phonegap, so I went throught this tutorial [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html][1] [1]: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Catlog:

```
   08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.apache.cordova.example/org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.apache.cordova.example-1.apk]
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.apache.cordova.example-1.apk]
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-09 14:36:21.752: E/AndroidRuntime(543):  ... 11 more
```

**Updated** MainActivity:

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

**My .jar folder is called "libs".**

**I have added cordova2.0.0.jar as build path.**

**I have tried adding plugins.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="com.phonegap.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="com.phonegap.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="com.phonegap.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="com.phonegap.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="com.phonegap.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="com.phonegap.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="com.phonegap.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="com.phonegap.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="Crypto" value="com.phonegap.CryptoHandler"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="com.phonegap.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="Network Status" value="com.phonegap.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="com.phonegap.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="com.phonegap.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="com.phonegap.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="com.phonegap.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="com.phonegap.Capture"/>
</plugins>
```

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="org.apache.cordova.example" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="cordovaExample" android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the package/activity name provided in your manifest.xml doesnt match the package/class name from your java file.
That is what it's looking for:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample
```

And that is what it gets:

```
package com.example.yourappname;
...
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
...
}
```

How does your manifest.xml look like?
Probably a copy-paste-error ;)

Comment: Okey I jst tried matching around and getting it same but still have not solved the problem, any guess why?

Comment: in your manifest, there is still `cordovaExample` as an activity name while you have no such activity.
I suggest changing that value or renaming you activity in your java file.

Comment: so:
- your class is now named "cordovaExample"
- your package reads: "org.apache.cordova.example"
- your file is named like your class

and it still shows the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issues, irritating...  now i got the temporary solution... copy the below files from any working project and pace in Current project..

```
ant.properties
build.xml
proguard-project.txt
project.properties
.classpath
.project
```

NOTE: Replace all files at a time..
On updating work space i this issue raised to me..
it's working for me.. but didnt got the exact solution...
import the example project once.. **Phonegap/lib/android/example** for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem as you. I followed this [link](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html)

I got the same error. By mistake i copied the whole Manifest file. But later i reverted back to the Manifest that Eclipse created for me and changed only the parts which are required for using phonegap.I followed the steps listed in the above link and it worked. (Ubuntu 10.04, Eclipse Kepler)